# Rails 5 testing NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading an existing application from Rails 4 to 5.0.0.beta2. It's actually running beautifully!

But, I am running into problems with controller tests. It throws this error:

```
    E

    Error:
    SeiteControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
    NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

    bin/rails test test/controllers/seite_controller_test.rb:14

    Finished in 1.068562s, 0.9358 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

    1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is the code (using standard test_helper):

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class SeiteControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      setup do 

      end

      test "should get index" do
        #get :index
      end

    end
```

Line 14 is the "test should get index" line. Needless to say if I un-comment the "get :index" line, I get the same error.

Comment: Can you share the code for the `SeiteController`?

Answer (score 0):

I had what appears to be the same problem. What fixed it for me was to put the following at the end of `test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Rails::Controller::Testing::TestProcess
  include Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions
  include Rails::Controller::Testing::Integration
end
```